# Why am I getting a Key Error for a string to be used for a POST request?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, post, keyerror

I'm currently learning Python by coding a very basic stock market trading algorithm. I've come across a little bit of a problem regarding my function I've written to submit orders. This function takes a string and submits it to the API using the python requests package. However, when I run my code, when I get to the section that defines the string to be submitted, the function fails and returns a Key error.

Variable definition:

```
data_unprocessed = '{"accountSpec": "Spec", "accountId": 397032, "action": {}, "symbol": "MESU1", "orderQty": {}, "orderType": "Market", "isAutomated": True }'.format(buy_or_sell,qty)
```

And here is the error that's returned:

```
data_unprocessed = '{ "accountSpec": "Spec", "accountId": 397032, "action": {}, "symbol": "MESU1", "orderQty": {}, "orderType": "Market", "isAutomated": "True" }'.format(buy_or_sell,qty) 
KeyError: ' "accountSpec"'
```

anyone know why I'm getting a key error when I'm defining this variable as a string, and not a data dictionary? the error corresponds to this line in the code where the variable is defined.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
def place_order(long_or_short, switching):
    global qty
    headers = {
            'accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization':'Bearer '+main_authenticator.access_token,
            }
    if long_or_short == "long":
        buy_or_sell = "Buy"
    if long_or_short == "short":
        buy_or_sell = "Sell"
    if switching == True:
        qty = "2"
    else:
        qty = "1"
    data_unprocessed = '{"accountSpec": "Spec", "accountId": 397032, "action": {}, "symbol": "MESU1", "orderQty": {}, "orderType": "Market", "isAutomated": True }'.format(buy_or_sell,qty)
    response = requests.post('https://endpoint.endpoint.com/endpoint', headers=headers, data=data_unprocessed)
    response_message = response.content
    print(response_message)
```

Comment: Can you post the function? There is no way to tell what precisely is causing the `KeyError`.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan yes absolutely -- here it is. should be there now

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are some data which do not have values with the key `accountSpec`

Try using errorHandling

```
try :
<< your code >>
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Check if this works.

2)Maybe your formatting has some issues..
try:

```
data_unprocessed = f'{"accountSpec": "Spec", "accountId": 397032, "action": {buy_or_sell}, "symbol": "MESU1", "orderQty": {qty}, "orderType": "Market", "isAutomated": True }'
```

Comment: do you think it has something to do with the .format string modifications? When I take the .format out, the code runs and defines the string. however, I definitely need to include the .format and the {} insertion points. when I add these back in, the key error returns

Comment: still not working -- it really does not like that "accountSpec" for whatever reason